# Adding Query result to label string

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have a label that I want a standard message to display "Today's Total: " how would I add my query result to the end of that string on the label.

```
var sql = @" SELECT COUNT (RTFPressTableID) AS NumberOfTables
             FROM RTFPressTables
             WHERE PressCloseTime BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @Date), '06:00:00') 
             AND  DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day, 0, @Date), '23:59:59') ";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ; Initial Catalog = ; Integrated Security = True"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        command.Parameters["@Date"].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
        Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());                    

        if (count > 0)
        {                        
           todaysTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(count.ToString());
            if (count >= 100)
            {
                todaysTotal.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            todaysTotal.Text = "Todays Total: 0";
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: And what happens when you run this code?

Comment: It's not completely clear from your question, but perhaps instead of `todaysTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(count.ToString());` you just want `todaysTotal.Text = $"Today's total: {count}";`

Comment: It will just display a number value. As an example if the query returns a value of 98 I want it to show up on my label as "Today's Total: 98".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with a similar problem as mine the answer iakobski gave me was a correct solution. Changing

```
 todaysTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(count.ToString());
```

to

```
  todaysTotal.Text = $"Today's Total: {count}";
```